# How do I place a symbol into an argument list

Tags: r, arguments, symbols

Given a [`symbol`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/name):

```
sym <- as.symbol("x")
```

I want to create an [`alist`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/list) with that symbol as the name.

```
correct_answer <- alist(x = )
```

The following doesn't quite work because it places `NULL` as the value.

```
setNames(list(NULL), deparse(sym))
```

The first element of the answer seems to be an empty symbol.

```
class(correct_answer[[1]])
## [1] "name"
deparse(correct_answer[[1]])
## [1] ""
```

However you can't create an empty symbol using `as.symbol()`.

```
as.symbol("")
## Error in as.symbol("") : attempt to use zero-length variable name
```

How do I place a symbol into an argument list?

Comment: @frank Fixed. The question mutated as I wrote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, list of arguments can be created using `formals` function. I am comparing your answer with the `formals`

**using `alist()`  - as per @Richie Cotton's answer**

```
sym1 <- as.symbol('x')
sym2 <- as.symbol('y')
sym3 <- as.symbol('z')
str(c(setNames(alist(dummy = ), deparse(sym1)),
      setNames(alist(dummy = ), deparse(sym2)),
      setNames(alist(dummy = ), deparse(sym3))))

# List of 3
# $ x: symbol 
# $ y: symbol 
# $ z: symbol
```

**without `alist()`**

using `formals` without symbols

```
str(formals(function(x,y,z){}))
# Dotted pair list of 3
# $ x: symbol 
# $ y: symbol 
# $ z: symbol
```

using `formals` with symbols

```
c_alist <- function( x )
{
  setNames( formals(c_alist), deparse(x) )   # or # setNames( formals(c_alist), as.character(x) )
}
str(sapply( c(sym1, sym2, sym3), c_alist ) )
# $ x: symbol 
# $ y: symbol 
# $ z: symbol
```

Comment: I was showing alternative way to get the same list of symbols.

Comment: @RichScriven I added `c_alist` function which is using symbols. Please take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a dummy `alist`, then override the name by deparsing the symbol.

```
setNames(alist(dummy = ), deparse(sym))
```